# Proof of the existence of a skew-symmetric orthogonal matrix with even number of dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove, that there exists a matrix A with even number of dimensions that is both skew-symmetric and orthogonal:

$$\tag{1}A^{T}=-A=A^{-1}.$$

I only found posts, where people just post some matrix and say, that it satisfies both the criteria, but I didn't manage to find a formal proof of the existence.

Comment: The problem formulation seems a bit confused.  Perhaps you are trying to prove that there exists a matrix (of even dimension) which is *both* skew-symmetric and orthogonal.  It should be clear that not every $A$ satisfying (1) must also satisfy (2).  But a weak problem formulation would be merely that some (even-dimensioned) matrix satisfies (1), and other $A$ will satisfy (2).  However the manner of your presentation seems to want to express a connection between (1) and (2).  Do you know what that connection is, or is the discovery of a connection the real crux of your Question?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, that's right, I want to prove that there exists a matrix (of even dimension) which is both skew-symmetric and orthogonal. Sorry for the incorrect formulation. I do understand, that not not every A satisfying (1) also satisfies (2), and, since I didn't manage to find posts relevant to my question, I decided to ask it here.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification.  My hint is to think about the real $2\times 2$ case.  If you get an example there, you can parlay it into all even dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the example $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & I_n\\-I_n & 0\end{array}\right].$